# how to make a method work - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, methods

I would like to add the following method to my object:

"  hello - this method logs to the console the string "Hello, my name is "
        followed by the actor's name. "

Could someone help me to find where I am wrong with this code? :

```
function Person (firstName, lastName, age, numOscars) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName;

  this.age = age;
  this.numOscars = numOscars;

  hello : function greeting() {
        console.log ("Hello, my name is " + this.firstName);
  }
}

var actors = new Array ();

actors[0] = new Person ("Leonardo", "DiCaprio", 41, 1);
actors[1] = new Person ("Jennifer", "Lawrence", 25, 1);
actors[2] = new Person ("Samuel L."," Jackson", 67, false);
actors[3] = new Person ("Meryl", "Streep", 66, 3);
actors[4] = new Person ("John", "Cho", 43, false);

Person.hello();
```

---

Thank you so much in advance ;)

Comment: Aside: *"How many Oscars you got?" – "False"* – Seems like a weird value. The *number of Oscars* if you have no Oscars is `0`, not `false`.

Comment: you've mixed up function body syntax and object method declaration when assigning fn `greeting` to `hello`.
You need just to assign that fn to `this.hello` property inside your constructor, like you did to `firstName`, `lastName` and other properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `hello` to

```
this.hello=function(){
  //Rest of code
}
```

Loop through actors and call `hello` method

```
actors.forEach(function(item) {

  item.hello();
})
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/4dcyxsh1/)

Comment: Using `prototype` would be much more preferable.

Answer (score 0):

You might be beginner :) You are mixing object literal notation with the constructor. Correct version of constructor function is below

```
function Person (firstName, lastName, age, numOscars) {    
  this.firstName = firstName;    
  this.lastName = lastName;    
  this.age = age;    
  this.numOscars = numOscars;

  this.hello = function () {
      console.log ("Hello, my name is " + this.firstName);    
  }
}
```

Comment: Using `prototype` would be much more preferable.

Answer (score 0):

First define your function like

```
function sayHello (firstName, lastName, age, numOscars) {
      console.log("Hello my name is ", firstName," ", lastName, "I am", age, "years old, and I have ", numOscars, " Oscar(s).");
}
```

create your actors array like this, you can add more objects to it.

```
var actors = [{firstName: "Leonardo", lastName: "DiCaprio", age: "42", numOscars: 1}, {firstName: "example", lastName: "something", age: "12", numOscars: 0}];
```

and you can call your function either individually like:

```
var leonardo = actors[0]
sayHello(leonardo.firstName, leonardo.lastName, leonardo.age, leonardo.numOscars);
```

or using forEach:

```
actors.forEach(function(actor) {
   sayHello(actor.firstName, actor.lastName, actor.age, actor.numOscars);
   console.log('\n');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function Person(firstName, lastName, age, numOscars) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName;
  this.age = age;
  this.numOscars = numOscars;
}

  // If hello function is added to Person functions prototype
  // then each time a new Person object is created, 
  // hello function gets inherited rather than creating a new hello function
  Person.prototype.hello = function greeting() {
      // here firstName always refer to the specific object to which belongs
      console.log("Hello, my name is " + this.firstName);
  }

// instead of new Array()
// Use short hand form of Array declaration also called Array literal notation
var actors =[];


// create a new person object and add it to actors array
actors.push(new Person("Leonardo", "DiCaprio", 41, 1));
actors.push(new Person("Jennifer", "Lawrence", 25, 1));
actors.push(new Person("Samuel L."," Jackson", 67, false));
actors.push(new Person("Meryl", "Streep", 66, 3));
actors.push(new Person("John", "Cho", 43, false));

// loop through each of actors array members and call 
// hello function
actors.forEach(function(actor){
  actor.hello();
});
```